# Confusion in usage of In / within

Tags: prepositions

In the given sentence which one is more appropriate between **in** and **within**:

> The voice __________ you.

If one replaces **you** with **me**, which preposition (in or within) will be the most appropriate?

The sentence thus formed is:

> The voice __________ me.

Does the word after the preposition affect the usage of the preposition in this case?

Answer (score 0):

For me *within* is much better but yes, it does depend on the word that follows.

*The voice within me*
*The voice within you*

But

*The voice in my head*

Possibly this is because *head* is a much more concrete entity than *me*.

Comment: For me "the voice in my head" sounds a lot scarier and less controllable than "the voice within my head"